Cannot send video messages on iOS 17
I don't know exactly how long this problem has been going on, but it's been at least since 17.6. I am currently on 17.7 and the problem is still occurring.
Whenever I try to send a video, the video does not send. For iMessages, the blue bar at the top remains there for 5+ minutes until it decides to fail at some point. For regular text messages, the video fails to send immediately, with the red (!) saying that it could not be delivered. I thought it might be the fact that I have Low-Data mode on for my Wi-Fi network, but disabling that does not affect it, and the problem persists on other Wi-Fi networks.
It does not matter if I am using Wi-Fi or connected to cellular. I can AirDrop the video to my Mac and send it just fine from there.
